# Group by not working in Grafana/prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

In Grafana I'm trying to draw a counter with the following formula

```
sum(increase(eventStore_successCounter_total[$__interval])) by (host)
```

Because I'm doing a group-by `host` I don't expect it to show 3 curves for the same host

[image]

Although I don't show the `host` in the legend I can assure you that all 3 curves have the same host. Also, when I remove the `by (host)` part I get the graph I was expecting

[image]

So my question is, why didn't the `by (host)` work. Is this really a "GROUP BY" ?

Comment: You misconfigured the `Legend` option. Try to put nothing in it or `auto` or `{{host}}`. It should show you the host name.

Comment: Yes, it will show the hostname if I put `{{host}}` but 3 times the same hostname. In my first image you can kind of see this because you see 3 graphs.

Comment: In your first image, it doesn't display the hostname but the text you wrote in `legend` option. Try to run your query in Prometheus UI, you will see better if there is an issue.

Comment: I you're right, I indeed misconfigured my legend. Stupid mistake. I used `$host` instead of `{{host}}`. Thanks for the help!!